# Web service discovery required Java

Tags: java, web-services, soapui, soap-client

I am tasked with developing something like this:

We have 3 or 4 web services which we host on JBoss, and would like to allow users to test the service. But SOAP UI is too technical for the users so we need to provide something easier,

The flow is something like:

- Get a HTML page with a drop down list listing all available web services
- After user selects a web service, user is presented with an option to input some data or select XML file with data.
- The user hits invoke web service button , and the web service is invoked with the data passed to the service as a parameter, then the result returned compared with expected result whether programaticaly or manually.

This looks like a relatively complex piece of development provided that it does not really add value, other than cater for technically incompetent users who find SOAP UI too technically complex.

Are there any tools ready out of the box that at least simplify some of this work , 
like display available services?

Any help is appreciated,

if there are no tools suggestions on how to achieve desired functionality is welcome.

PS: Web services are developed with CXF Java and hosted on JBoss, for simplicity we can assume latest version of above mentioned technology will be used.